# Is there some way to improve my usage of C# generic so I don't need to duplicate some declaration?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm designing a Stats system for a game (e.g. move speed, attack power, etc). I've landed on the following solution (stripped down for the purposes of the question)

Base class for all stats. A stat can be int, float, bool, etc.

```csharp
public abstract class Stat<T> 
{
    public abstract T GetStat(int level) {}
}
```

Sample implementation of a stat for Attack Power, which is a float value:

```csharp
public class AttackPower : Stat<float>
{
    float floatStat = 10f;

    public override float GetStat(int level)
    {
        return floatStat * level; //placeholder behaviour
    }
}
```

I want to be able to 'Level up' a stat while the game is running, so for example the player might want to increase their attack power. So I implemented this class to pair a Stat with a Level

```csharp
public class RuntimeStat<T,Z> where T: Stat<Z>
{
    public int Level { get; private set; }
    T Stat { get; }

    Y Value => Stat.GetStat(Level);

    public RuntimeStat(T stat) 
    {
        Stat = stat;
    }

    public void LevelUp()
    {
        Level++;
    }
}
```

And to actually use the stat, this is how it would work in the Character class:

```csharp
public class SomeCharacterClass
{
    RuntimeStat<AttackPower, float> AttackPower;

    public SomeCharacterClass()
    {
        AttackPower = new RuntimeStat<AttackPower, float>();
    }

    public void Attack()
    {
        Debug.Log($"Attack for {AttackPower.Value} damage!");
    }
}
```

Notice that in my RuntimeStat I had to define 2 generic types, one for which stat class I want to use at runtime (`AttackPower`), and what kind of value I'm expecting (`float`).

What I want to know is, is there some way I can improve this so that I don't need to define `float` twice in my code for `AttackPower`? `AttackPower` itself already extends `Stat` as a `Stat<float>` so it seems less than ideal to also have to define it for `RuntimeStat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why "stat" would need to be generic, however, what you are looking for is [generic constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters).

[Since .NET 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/#generic-math) (or perhaps only from .NET 7 (which should be released in a few months), since documentation for this isn't available for .NET 6) this has finally been enabled: [INumber interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumber-1?view=net-7.0)

So you can add `where T : INumber`.

I recommend you name the generic type `TStat` and not `T` though for clarity.

Once you have declared that the generic type is a number, you'll be able to use the `Increment` method via `++` [(documentation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.iincrementoperators-1.op_increment?view=net-7.0#system-numerics-iincrementoperators-1-op-increment(-0)).

If you must use generics (which I doubt for this specific case) and you must use an older .NET version, you can write this less efficiently by checking the type of the generic type and calling the correct method accordingly in a case statement.

Comment: I'm guessing this is Unity which means .NET 6 isn't an option (I think, at least it didn't used to be!)

Comment: @DavidG as I said, I don't think generics are actually needed here. In games, either all the stats are integer-like types or all or floating point types. It seems strange to mix them.

Comment: Yup, I agree with that.

Comment: @DavidG anyway, I added another option.

Comment: Yeah, it is Unity so .NET 6 is not available yet. 

So I already use generic constraints on `RuntimeStat`, but perhaps I can take it further? If I implement something like `RuntimeFloat` that's like `public class RuntimeFloat<TStat> : RuntimeStat<TStat, float> where TStat : Stat<float>` then I can just use `RuntimeFloat<AttackPower>`, it's a little bit extra work but I think it's cleaner this way what do you think?

Comment: Oh and the reason I'm mixing the value types is some stats just make sense as whole numbers, like 'number of projectiles' that you fire out of a gun, it doesn't make sense to fire 3.34 bullets. But it does make sense for your attack power to be 232.56

Comment: @Arvin if you have two types of stats, you can create a base class for them and two specific types, then inherit from the correct type. In this case you don't need generics. Btw, I've used generics a lot, usually for serialization (and similar) infra though.

Comment: I see, I think you might be right. I can just have  FloatStat, IntStat, etc, I suppose the generic is unnecessary